# Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe: Trigger event from handlebars

Tags: ember.js

In the init of my view I have setup the event listening as follows:

```
 Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("inlineEdit.makeBlue", {
    before: function (name, timestamp, payload) {
       alert(name, timestamp,payload);
    },
    after: function () {

    }
  });
```

From handlebars I would like to trigger the event with an action:

```
<a {{action inlineEdit.makeBlue on="mouseDown"}} class="btn ">Blue</a>
```

Unfortunately this does not trigger the above event listener. Can an instrumenation event be triggered from handlebars? If yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment isn't avaliable in the ember core, but it's possible to implement.

When you use the actions internally ember will use the `Ember.ActionHandler#send` method to dispatch these events. So you can reopen that class, and proxy the method, wrapping the invocation in a `Ember.instrument`:

```
Ember.ActionHandler.reopen({
    send: function(actionName) {
        var orininalArguments = arguments, 
            args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1), 
            result;        
        Ember.instrument('action.' + actionName, args, function() {            
            result = this._super.apply(this, orininalArguments);
        }, this);        
        return result;
    }
});
```

So you can subscribe:

```
// Specific action
Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("action.inlineEdit.makeBlue", { ... })
```

I added the `action` prefix in the subscription, so you can take advantage of the instrumentation api, and listen all action events with:

```
// All actions
Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("action", { ... })
```

Give a look in that fiddle to see this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8P46f/

I hope it helps